# Understanding a Fourier Series Problem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I found the following problem on Fourier Series. But I cannot make sense about how $f(x)$ could be a $1$-periodic function on the interval $[-1,1]$? Could you please help me make sense out of this problem?

Let $f$ be the $1$-periodic function such that $f(x) = |x|$ for $x \in [−1,1]$. Determine explicitly a sequence of trigonometric polynomials $(p_N )_N$ such that $p_N \rightarrow f$ uniformly as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: what the heck? what does the question have to do with fourier series or being 1-periodic on $[-1,1]$?? an easy example would be $f = 0$ and $f_n$ the indicator of some set $E_n$, where the $E_n$'s jump around a lot on $[0,1]$ but go to $0$ in measure.

Comment: Opps, i'm really sorry. I copy & pasted the wrong problem! its fixed now.

Comment: I would guess it means 2-periodic